# Why does my comboBox not allow me to add values to it?

Tags: c#, windows-8, combobox, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I have this WinRT XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboxGroupName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="4" Width="200" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ></ComboBox>
```

When I click in it to enter a new value, though, it seems to convert itself into a readonly textbox (it loses its down arrow and disallows any typing into it). What do I need to do to allow adding values into the comboBox? Or do I need to use a separate TextBox to do that (I reckon so, but I'd like to avoid that if reasonably possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your only option will be to use a seperate TextBox. There is an [`IsEditable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.iseditable.aspx) property, but it states:

> Gets a value that indicates whether the user can edit text in the text box portion of the ComboBox. This property always returns false.

and the [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br209348.aspx) Page states:

> You populate the ComboBox by adding objects directly to the Items collection or by binding the ItemsSource property to a data source. Items added to the ComboBox are wrapped in ComboBoxItem containers.